# How do I convert a SharePoint 2010 master page to SharePoint 2013 master page?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server, master-page

What is the best approach to converting a SP 2010 master page into a SP 2013 master page?

After performing an upgrade from SP 2010 to 2013, our public facing website lost its style and structure. Also when I attempt to browse to the website after setting the master page to the old 2010 master page, the page breaks or fails to load.

After researching it came to me that the master page structure may have controls that are either deprecated or changed.

Do I need to start from scratch to create this new site meaning fresh html? If so how I port of over web parts and special controls from old master page?

Very curious to see what other have experienced about with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 introduces a new user interface that is lightweight, fast, and fluid. This UI is built by using new CSS styles, themes, and master pages. To get this new experience, you must upgrade to the new UI. But the significant changes that were made to support the new UI may break the upgrade story for some scenarios where you use custom branding.

This article from MSFT give you more details about the issue.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178510(v=office.15).aspx

if you have features refrenced to the master page:
[Use Feature upgrade to apply new SharePoint 2013 master pages when upgrading from SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn673597(v=office.15).aspx)

Custom mater page can not be upgrade automatically, You need to rewrite the master-page which fits to SP 2013 look and feel, placeholders etc.

Check the response from this anwser from MSFT.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad08e4b9-544f-46a7-939c-03096d098a68/upgrade-custom-master-page-to-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin